# C# Entity Framework Using the Repository and Unit of Work Pattern for Multiple DB Transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have defined three tables, `Parts`, `Models` and `PartModel`.
For each `Part` row, there may be multiple `Models` row defined, and they are joined in a relationship via the `PartModel` table.

**Parts**

```
ID  PartName
1   Motorcycle
2   Cars
```

**Models**

```
ID  ModelName
1   Suzuki
2   Yamaha
3   Toyota
4   Nissan
```

**PartModel**

```
ID    PartID         ModelID
1       1               1
2       1               2
3       2               3
4       2               4
```

**C# Models**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

namespace TestApplication.Model
{
    [Table("Parts")]
    public partial class Parts
    {
        [Key]
        public int PartID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string PartName { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Models")]
    public partial class Models
    {
        [Key]
        public int ModelID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("PartModel")]
    public partial class PartModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int PartModelID { get; set; }

        public int PartID { get; set; }

        public int ModelID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here are my repository classes:

**BaseRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Transactions;

namespace TestApplication.Data
{
    public abstract class BaseRepository<TContext> : IDisposable
        where TContext : class, new()
    {
        private readonly bool startedNewUnitOfWork;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork<TContext> unitOfWork;
        private readonly TContext context;
        private bool disposed;

        public BaseRepository()
            : this(null)
        {
        }

        public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork<TContext> unitOfWork)
        {
            if (unitOfWork == null)
            {
                this.startedNewUnitOfWork = true;
                this.unitOfWork = BeginUnitOfWork();
            }
            else
            {
                this.startedNewUnitOfWork = false;
                this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            }

            this.context = this.unitOfWork.Context;
            this.disposed = false;
        }


        ~BaseRepository()
        {
            this.Dispose(false);
        }


        protected TContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                return this.context;
            }
        }

        public IUnitOfWork<TContext> UnitOfWork
        {
            get
            {
                return this.unitOfWork;
            }
        }


        public void Commit()
        {
            this.unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        public void Rollback()
        {
            this.unitOfWork.Rollback();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    DisposeManagedResources();
                }

                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void DisposeManagedResources()
        {
            if (this.startedNewUnitOfWork && (this.unitOfWork != null))
            {
                this.unitOfWork.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public IUnitOfWork<TContext> BeginUnitOfWork()
        {
            return BeginUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        }

        public static IUnitOfWork<TContext> BeginUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        {
            return new UnitOfWorkFactory<TContext>().Create(isolationLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

**IRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestApplication.Data
{
    public interface IRepository<TContext, TEntity, TKey>
        where TContext : class
        where TEntity : class        
    {
        IUnitOfWork<TContext> UnitOfWork { get; }

        List<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderByMethod = null, string includePaths = "");
        TEntity FindByID(TKey id);
        List<TEntity> FindAll();
        void Add(TEntity entity, Guid userId);
        void Update(TEntity entity, Guid userId);
        void Remove(TKey id, Guid userId);
        void Remove(TEntity entity, Guid userId);
    }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestApplication.Data
{
    public class Repository<TContext, TEntity, TKey> : BaseRepository<TContext>, IRepository<TContext, TEntity, TKey>
        where TContext : class, new()
        where TEntity : class        
    {
        private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

        private DbContext CurrentDbContext
        {
            get
            {
                return Context as DbContext;
            }
        }

        public Repository()
            : this(null)
        {
        }

        public Repository(IUnitOfWork<TContext> unitOfWork)
            : base(unitOfWork)
        {
            _dbSet = CurrentDbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual List<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderByMethod = null, string includePaths = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

            if (predicate != null)
                query = query.Where(predicate);

            if (includePaths != null)
            {
                var paths = includePaths.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                query = paths.Aggregate(query, (current, path) => current.Include(path));
            }

            var entities = orderByMethod == null ? query.ToList() : orderByMethod(query).ToList();

            return entities;
        }

        public virtual TEntity FindByID(TKey id)
        {
            var entity = _dbSet.Find(id);

            return entity;
        }

        public virtual List<TEntity> FindAll()
        {
            return Find();
        }

        public virtual void Add(TEntity entity, Guid userId)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            _dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entity, Guid userId)
        {
            if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
            CurrentDbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Remove(TKey id, Guid userId)
        {
            var entity = _dbSet.Find(id);
            Remove(entity, userId);
        }

        public virtual void Remove(TEntity entity, Guid userId)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            if (CurrentDbContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
                _dbSet.Attach(entity);

            _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

**PartsRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using TestApplication.Model;

namespace TestApplication.Data
{
    public class PartsRepository : Repository<DBContext, Parts, int>
    {
        public PartsRepository() : this(null) { }
        public PartsRepository(IUnitOfWork<DBContext> unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork) { }
    }
}
```

**ModelsRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using TestApplication.Model;

namespace TestApplication.Data
{
    public class ModelsRepository : Repository<DBContext, Models, int>
    {
        public ModelsRepository() : this(null) { }
        public ModelsRepository(IUnitOfWork<DBContext> unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork) { }
    }
}
```

**PartModelRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using TestApplication.Model;

namespace TestApplication.Data
{
    public class PartModelRepository : Repository<DBContext, PartModel, int>
    {
        public PartModelRepository() : this(null) { }
        public PartModelRepository(IUnitOfWork<DBContext> unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork) { }

        public PartModel GetPartModelByModelID(ModelID)
        {
            // LINQ Query here to get the PartModel object based on the ModelID
            var q = (from a in this.Context.PartModel.Where(a => a.ModelID == ModelID)
                             select a);
            PartModel partModel = q.FirstOrDefault();
            return partModel;
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to use the repository to say, for example, I wanted to delete the model 1 (Suzuki), I can perform multiple table delete in a single transaction so that I can be assured that the data will be deleted from both tables `Model` and `PartModel`.

Currently, my codes are as follows (this works but notice that I am committing on both Repository calls, which then has the tendency where one transaction may fail but still the changes to the database would be pushed on the other repository call):

```
public bool DeleteModel(int ModelID)
{
    // Get the PartModel based on the ModelID
    using(PartModelRepository partModelRepo = new PartModelRepository())
    {
        PartModel partModel = partModelRepo.GetPartModelByModelID(ModelID);
        partModelRepo.Remove(partModel, Guid.NewGuid());
        partModel.Commit();
    }

    // Delete the Model
    using(ModelsRepository modelRepo = new ModelsRepository())
    {
        Models model = modelRepo.FindByID(ModelID);
        modelRepo.Remove(model, Guid.NewGuid());
        modelRepo.Commit();
    }
}
```

How would I be able to translate this so that I can have a single `Commit` for both DB delete commands?

I tried the following:

```
public bool DeleteModel(int ModelID)
{
    // Get the PartModel based on the ModelID
    using(ModelsRepository modelsRepo = new ModelsRepository())
    {
        using(PartModelRepository partModelRepo = new PartModelRepository(modelsRepo.UnitOfWork))
        {
            PartModel partModel = partModelRepo.GetPartModelByModelID(ModelID);
            partModelRepo.Remove(partModel, Guid.NewGuid());

            Models model = modelRepo.FindByID(ModelID);
            modelRepo.Remove(model, Guid.NewGuid());
            modelRepo.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

But it is throwing an error saying something about FK Constraint Violation.

I do understand that I am deleting the `PartModel` and the `Model`, but it seems it can't take both delete actions into a single transaction operation.

Appreciate any input.

**UPDATE**

As some people have posted here, I have updated my code to utilize Transactions as recommended by [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843).

```
public bool DeleteModel(int ModelID)
    {
        // Get the PartModel based on the ModelID

        using (var transaction = this.Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            PartModel partModel = this.Context.PartModel.First(s => s.ModelID == ModelID);
            Models model = this.Context.Models.First(s => s.ModelID == ModelID);

            this.Context.PartModel.Remove(partModel);
            this.Context.Models.Remove(model);

            this.Context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I traced the database call using MS SQL Profiler and the commands being issued are correct. The issue I am having is that it seems that the changes are not being persisted to the database.

I used a try catch block on the above code, but no error is being thrown, hence, I know that the operation is ok.

Any ideas on where to look further?

Comment: I keep saying this: generic repositories suck. Just work with the context and its `DbSet`s and all this is so much easier. But if you insist on doing this, then do it right. Repositories shouldn't save data, UoW's should do that, and the repos should share the same context provided by the UoW. (And where is the `Commit` method in your code?)

Comment: In the method public bool DeleteModel(int ModelID), notice that I have both repository doing a .Commit() call for each repo.Remove(object) call.

Comment: Yeah, but where's the method itself? Why isn't in in the generic repo?

Comment: `IUnitOfWork` **interface** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbContext` is aware of ambient transactions.

To do show, reference `System.Transactions` in your project and enclose all the actions inside a block like this, which instances a [TrasnactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using(var ts = new TransactinScope())
{
    // inside transaction scope

    // run all the transactional operations here

    // call .Complete to "commit" them all
    ts.Complete();
}
```

If there is an exception, or you don't call `ts.Complete()` or you explicitly call `ts.Dispose()` the transaction, which means all the operations inside the block, is rolled back.

For example, you can modify your `public bool DeleteModel(int ModelID)` including a `using` that wraps all the operations, and they'll share the same transaction.

**Update:**

Just to add more to this answer, since I am mostly performing data related changes, I have opted to use [Database.BeginTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843).

Comment: Can you show me where inside my code will I place this? Like the public bool DeleteModel codes would be placed inside the using TransactionScope?

Comment: Would I still need to explicitly call .Commit() for each repo.Remove(obj, ID) call?

Comment: No, batuta. You run all the functions that want to happen in the same transaction inside the using block. And, when they all have run, you call ts.Complete(), which commits all the pending changes. If you don't call .Complete() all the changes made to the database frominside the using block will be discarded. That's way I tell you that you move all the code inside the using block. Don't call .Complete() until all the operations have been done. It works as if you did a BEGIN TRAN at the opening curly braces, and a COMMIT at the .Complete().

Comment: So I won't be using any of those repo.Remove(obj, ID) and instead use DbContext outright? Can you modify your answer to include the codes that I have?

Comment: You can use DbContext,your repo, or even higher level business logic, because the ambient transaction will be detected by any DbContext which is used inside the block,now matter how deeply in the chain call it's invoked. I.e. the DbContext doesn't need to be right their in the using block: they can be in a method called by another method call by another method and so on. For example, if you run a business logic class that uses a repo that uses a DbContext,it will joint to the transaction, without doing nothing special in the code.

Comment: Would be good if you could show some example code of what you were trying to advise, from the context I have specified in the question. I still don't quite get it.

Comment: @Batuta: it's extremely easy, it's in the answer: put inside the transaction scope block whatever blocks of codes, including method invocations, or whatever you want, that use DbContexts. All of them will be executed in the same transaction. What is what you don't understand about it? I think it's crystal clear. What do you want me to do? Implemente clasess or code to show them there. No, I'm not gong to do it. Please, if you don't understand read carefully... anything inside the block, anything inside the block, anything inside the block, whichever it is, will run in the same transaction

Comment: I updated the question and placed everything inside a transaction. The command is getting issued to the database but the changes are not being persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Net's TransactionScope class to do a Multi-database transaction. You'll still have to call SaveChanges() on each context separately within the transaction, but calling Commit() on the outer TransactionScope will do the final commit.

As far as your fk violation, I'd recommend using SqlServer profiler or a DB interceptor to trace the queries EF is executing. Sometimes you need to be more explicit in telling EF to delete dependencies: the trace should make it easy to tell what is t being deleted. Another thing to watch out for is that EF assumes FK relationships are Cascade On Delete by default. If you haven't disabled this in your configuration and EF is not the one generating your DB, then the mismatch can cause EF to assume it needs to issue fewer delete queries than is actually required.